# jQuery onload flip div

Tags: jquery, html, flip

OK, I'm using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("#flipPad a:not(.revert)").bind("click",function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $("#flipbox").flip({
                direction: $this.attr("rel"),
                color: $this.attr("rev"),
                content: $this.attr("title"), //(new Date()).getTime(),
                onBefore: function(){$(".revert").show()}
            });
            return false;
        });

        $(".revert").bind("click",function() {
            $("#flipbox").revertFlip();
            return false;
        });

        var changeMailTo = function() {
            var mArr = ["@","smashup","luca",".it"];
            $("#email").attr("href","mailto:"+mArr[2]+mArr[0]+mArr[1]+mArr[3]);
        }

        $(".downloadBtn").click(function() {
            pageTracker._trackPageview("download_flip");
        });

        setTimeout(changeMailTo,500);

    });
</script>
```

What this does is when I click on the flipPad button, the flipbox reverts [DEMO](http://umovies.org/joc/game.php?step=1)

Now what I want to do is to flip the div, but automatically.
I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#flipbox").flip({
            direction: $this.attr("rel"),
            color: $this.attr("rev"),
            content: $this.attr("title"), //(new Date()).getTime(),
            onBefore: function(){$(".revert").show()}
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: rel="bt" rev="#B0EB17" title="'.$text2.'"

Comment: Well since the property values (direction, color, content) came from the link that was clicked, how are you going to define those now on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not working because you were using `$(this)` which wasn't referring to anything rather than to the `#flipbox` as in the original function (that's what `$this = $(this)` was doing). This code should work for you (as long as there is **only one** `#flipbox` element)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var $boxToFlip = $('#flipbox');
  $boxToFlip.flip({
    direction: $boxToFlip.attr("rel"),
    color: $boxToFlip.attr("rev"),
    content: $boxToFlip.attr("title"),//(new Date()).getTime(),
    onBefore: function(){$(".revert").show()}
  })
});
```